# GitLab specific Syntax Highlighting Options

Tags: gitlab, lexer, gitattributes, rouge

I'm trying to specify [an option](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/blob/master/lib/rouge/lexers/lua.rb#L14) that is defined in the *LUA* lexer library that GitLab uses (ruby library [Rouge](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge)).

```
option :function_highlighting, 'Whether to highlight builtin functions (default: true)'
```

In the *.gitattributes* file at the root of my repository, I tried:

```
*.lua gitlab-language=lua?{function_highlighting=false}
```

and several other formats with no luck.

I couldn't find any information on options in the [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/highlighting.html).

Anyone knows the right syntax, or if options are supported in that context?